# Content of a NSMutableDictionnary erratically returned

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to add keys in a dictionnary in Objective-C. The code is as follows :

I have a class MyClass whose header file contains :

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dict;
```

This gets initialized as follows :

```
_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then I try to add keys to it :

```
- (void) addOrModify:(myKey*) key withValue:(myValue *) value {
[self.dict setObject:value forKey:key];
NSLog(@"Adding the key %@ %p with value %@ %p",[key description],key,[value description],value);
NSLog(@"%@",[self.dict description]);
}
```

And here is what I get upon adding different key/values :

```
Adding the key (key1) 0x7f9dc3590070 with value (value1) 0x7f9dc358e760
{
"(key1)" = "(value1)";
}

Adding the key (key2) 0x7f9dc357adc0 with value (value2) 0x7f9dc357de20
{
"(key2)" = (null);
"(key1)" = "(value1)";
}

Adding the key (key3) 0x7fa4d2cbdbd0 with value (value3) 0x7fa4d2d53cf0
{
"(key3)" = "(value3)";
"(key2)" = "(value2)";
"(key1)" = "(value1)";
}
```

Now if I take a look into the actual content of the dictionary with XCode's debugger, I find that all pairs key/value are present as they should. So it seems that the description method of dict fails to print correctly the value of some keys. The same happens without using NSLog but displaying the content of the dictionary in a UITable. Also note that if I try to log the address of the value for these particular keys, it also gives me 0x0 (so my description function is not at fault).

Note that the behavior is rather chaotic, sometimes several values are set to nil, then they appear correctly after I have added a few more pairs of key/values.  I really can't get my head around this problem, any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1**

The interface of my keys

```
@interface myKey : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *myKeyName;
@property(nonatomic) float myKeyFloat;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDate *dateCreated;
```

The interface of my values:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Unities) { g, kg, };
@interface myValue : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) float myValueFloat;
@property(nonatomic) Unities myValueUnit;
```

Calling code

```
- (IBAction)addKeyValue:(id)sender { 
myValue *value = [myValue randomValue]; 
myKey *key =[[CatalogKeys sharedCatalogKeys] 
getRandomKeyFromStore]; [self.dict addOrModify:key withValue: value]; 
}
```

where randomValue just set myValueUnit to 'g' and puts a random float in myValueFloat

Comment: It will assist people to help you if you add the definitions of the types `myKey` and `myValue` along at least with the code which calls `addOrModify` to your question.

Comment: I also tried to play with my code but couldn't find a definitive way to solve this problem. The only thing I found is that if I add [key description] instead of key into the dictionary the problem disappears. Then I reduced the class myKey to contain only a NSString but then again the problem reappears. What puzzles me most is the discrepency btw what NSLog prints and what I see in the debugger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess:

The information supplied does not show that your type `myKey` implements `isEqual:` and `hash`. Keys must implement these methods to work correctly in an `NSDictionary`; if they are not implemented the default `NSObject` implementations will be used and they probably do not produce the correct results for instances of `myKey`.

You also indicate that using the `description` of your `myKey` instances does work, this makes sense as `description` returns an `NSString` and that type implements `isEqual:` and `hash`.

HTH

Comment: Great !! I implemented the hash function (by just hashing by keyName) and this worked fine ! Thanks a lot.
By the way : I am wrong or NSDictionnary class documentation doesn't specify this hash definition constraint ?

Comment: Well `NSDictionary` states it uses `isEqual:`, and if look that up its definition states "*If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This last point is particularly important if you define isEqual: in a subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.*" So it's there, but not directly in the `NSDictionary` docs.